# How to render overlayed tracks with FFMPEG

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video

I'm trying to use FFMPEG to facilitate rendering of video with clip layouts similar to that of Premiere, Final Cut, etc.

For example, here is a visualization of a video with an intro, an opener with a small overlap on either side, some content, and then an outro that also overlaps the content.

[video clip layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KgM1.jpg)

This is one particular video layout, but you can see that the layout mimics what we're used to in Premiere or Final Cut.

I'm trying to use FFMEPG's filter graph to compose videos with layouts similar to the one above.

I've produced a number of such videos but I keep running into unexpected issues at unexpected times and I'm hoping that someone here can describe a robust way to accomplish such track positioning.

The primary tool that I'm using to accomplish these track layouts is the `overlay` filter. With the `overlay` filter, the remaining challenge comes down to how to fill empty video and audio space between clips on the same track.

Here's what I've tried and how it's failed.

**Transparent bitmap + anullsrc audio**

I produced a number of videos where I fill empty video space with a transparent PNG with a `TPad` set for the desired duration and the `stopMode` set to `clone`.

The audio is provided by `anullsrc`, combined with an `atrim` filter to set the desired duration.

This approach has worked for many videos but recently started causing problems. The issue is that the `anullsrc` seems to introduce noise. But it only happens on the tracks that actually begin with silent audio and then later include real audio. For example, look at the top track in the previously attached image.

I was never able to determine why the noise was generated. I tried messing with sample rates and other audio details. Eventually I gave up.

**Transparent and silent video clip**

Next, I rendered a 1 second long transparent, silent `.mov` video clip. I extended the transparent video with a `tpad` filter with a `stopMode` of `clone`. For the audio, I wasn't sure what to use so I went with `acopy`.

This approach worked for one video but then failed for all the others. When this approach fails, it reports that a bunch of frames were queued up and that something might be wrong, then FFMPEG hangs without any further progress and the process starts growing in RAM usage, quickly up to 100GB. I have to force stop the process.

**Audio delay**

Finally, since the audio seems to be the root of the issue, I kept the transparent clone for the video and I tried using `adelay` for the audio tracks. So instead of filling up all available time with audio, I would simply start each audio segment at the desired time.

For whatever reason, I can't seem to get `adelay` working correctly in my overall setup. All of the audio segments play at the beginning of the video. I have a fairly complicated filter graph so it's difficult to debug. I know the `adelay`s are in there, but it's possible that some other configuration in the graph is undoing them somehow.

**Conclusion**

I've tried pretty much everything I can think of to accomplish a very basic multilayer video layout but I can't get it to work consistently.

I assume that such a layout is a very common goal in video production, so I'm hoping that one of you have a robust approach to accomplish such a thing.

Comment: The layout in your exmaple image can be achieved with multiple xfade and acrossfade filters. See [Merging multiple video files with ffmpeg and xfade filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63570355/) for an example. Also, take a look at `melt` from MLT framework: it's a command-line editor.

Comment: xfade looks like it's just for cross-fade, but I want true overlay because the overlaid videos include the desired transition effect. I'll look into MLT.